# How to deploy REST Web Service using IIS

Tags: c#, rest, iis

I wrote a simple C# REST based Web Service by following

[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9vBxAH4f5E]

When I copy folder to IIS and create application by Add Application, I am getting Error 500. 
Is there something I am doing wrong ?
I have IIS v6 on Windows 7.
There is no main function, should I create console or web based application to render it ?
Any help or pointers will be great.